# VBA find and replace row entry

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a function that basically does the following:

1. Grabs a "name" cell value from workbook #1
2. Grabs an "amount" cell value from workbook #1
3. Opens 2nd workbook (which is a 2 column list where columnA = "Names" and columnB = "Amounts")
4. Scans column A of 2nd workbook for a duplicate "name" entry (from step 1)
5. If a duplicate exists, overwrites the corresponding "amount" value in column B with the value stored from step 2
6. If *no* duplicate exists, appends a new last row to the list
7. Writes "name" in last row of column A of 2nd workbook
8. Writes "amount" in last row of column B of 2nd workbook

Essentially, this function will update a list of names with their corresponding amounts.  If a name already exists on the list, this script will find the duplicate entry in column A, and update the associated amount in column B of the same row.  If a name doesn't exist on this list, the function will add a new row to the list and then write the stored "name" value in column A, and the stored "amount" value in column B.

I've got steps 1-3 working but I'm having some trouble creating the loops for 4-8.  Here's what I currently have for code... any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

```
Sub Open_Updator()

Dim proj_name As String
Dim amount As Double
Dim updator As Workbook
Dim updator_sheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long
Dim Destination As Range

proj_name_raw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cover").Range("C7").Value
proj_name = Left(proj_name_raw, Len(proj_name_raw) - 3)
amount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Range("O110").Value

Set updator = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\updator.xlsx")
updator.Activate

Set updator_sheet = Sheets("Table")

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
arr = Range("A1:B" & LastRow)
Set Destination = Range("A1")

For R = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    For C = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        If arr(R, C) = proj_name Then arr(R, C) = arr(R, 1)
    Next C
Next R

Destination.Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: can the names in the 1st workbook also be duplicated? If so, which value should be written in the 2nd workbook?

Comment: the "name" in the first workbook is the value from the same cell every time, so it won't be duplicated in the 1st workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Try this:

```
    Private Sub Test()

        Dim WB1 As Worksheet
        Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="WB1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim LastRow As Long
        Dim LastRowWB1 As Long

        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        LastRowWB1 = WB1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        j = 1

        For r = 2 To LastRowWB1
            Name = WB1.Cells(r, "A").Value
            For x = 2 To LastRow + j
                If Cells(x, "A").Value = Name Then
                    Cells(x, "B") = WB1.Cells(r, "B")
                    Exit For
                ElseIf Cells(x, "A") = "" Then
                    Cells((LastRow + j), "A") = WB1.Cells(r, "A").Value
                    Cells((LastRow + j), "B") = WB1.Cells(r, "B").Value
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            Next x
        Next r

    End Sub
```

You can also use Find:

```
Private Sub Test2()

    Dim WB1 As Worksheet
    Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="U:\Temp\WB1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim SrchInArray As Range

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowWB1 = WB1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    j = 1
    Set SrchInArray = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(LastRow, "A"))

    For r = 2 To LastRowWB1
        Name = WB1.Cells(r, "A").Value
        Set y = SrchInArray.Find(WB1.Cells(r, "A").Value, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False, False)
        If Not y Is Nothing Then
            Cells(y.Row, "B") = WB1.Cells(r, "B").Value
        Else
            Cells(LastRow + j, "A") = WB1.Cells(r, "A").Value
            Cells(LastRow + j, "B") = WB1.Cells(r, "B").Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

You will have to adjust some names. The code assumes that in both workbooks row 1 has labels, and names and values begin in row 2.

Let me know if you get stuck somewhere so we can work it out. Otherwise, provide a sample of your workbooks to adjust the code.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much!  I just had to make a few tweaks in order to get it to work with my system!  Thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: Glad it worked. If changes are significant/relevant perhaps consider posting them here for future reference.

Comment: The "For" loop with a nested "If" statement was what was giving me the most trouble... I updated the script to write the values I had already stored in variables and then I flipped which workbook was actually running the module.